# Remove group messages with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot by using `python-telegram-bot` and I added it to a group.

I want to specify a list, and if the sentences in the list are sent to the group, the telegram's robot will delete that message from the group.
What modules and codes should I use to do this?

Please give me a full description. I'm new

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far? People here are usually happier to help after you've shown what effort you've put in yourself; as it stands, this questions comes across as a "write the code for me" demand.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `delete_message` method in the `bot` object, as described in the `python-telegram-bot` [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.delete).

**Example**:

```
bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat_id,
               message_id=message.message_id,
               *args,
               **kwargs)
```

**Remember that there are some limitations**:

- A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
- Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
- If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
- If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.

Comment: @Sajjad I'm glad it helped. Could you select my aswer?

Comment: Yes thank you so much...

Comment: @Sajjad https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Is the 3rd point necessary?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i got, you want  to check if the message contains a word in a list and if so you have to delete it.

with the library you are using you can register a handler using a regex that is runned when the regex is True (checking the text of the message).
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.regexhandler.html
in the callback function you check if the chat is a group, if so then you can delete it doing

```
bot.deleteMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat.id, message_id=update.message.message_id)
```